# Execute immidiate: WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script

Tags: google-bigquery

When you put in a query in Bigquery, we can see how much data will be processed
[image]

But if you put in any execute immediate one, it cannot calculate, even when it's clear, e.g. below 0.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """SELECT 1""";
```

[image]

Any way to show the estimated processed size before running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Step 1 - replace `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with `SELECT`
2. Step 2 - run Script
3. Step 3 - Navigate to respective Result and Copy generated statement
4. Step 4 - Paste this statement into new Editor and see estimated processed bytes

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to know before actually processing the bytes? I am just very mindful of the monthly 1 TB free limit and do not want to accidentally process many GBs of data. The problem is that I want to make dynamic tables names, but it is pointless if cannot know how much data it will process before running it.

Comment: follow described steps to check generated sql (it will not run yet if you replace `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with `SELECT` - this will not process bytes just will give you the final sql statement that will be generated and in Step #4 you will be able to see processed bytes volume w/o actually processing it